# rails 3.1 ajax call seems to kill javascript listener

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1, I have a crud model Question. On the show page I list the related answers (@answer defined in controller)

There is a remote call link in the answers area that works fine using accepted nested attributes:

```
<span class="crud">
  <%= link_to 'Edit/Add Answers', edit_answers_question_path(params[:id]), :"data-remote" => true %>
</span>
```

Which replaces the @questions list with a form that allow editing/updating all the answers.

Questions has a jquery javascript questions.js (stubbed version that I can't get to fire)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-behavior="edit_contains"]').click(function(e) {
    var c = 1 
    alert(this);
    return(false)
  });
  $('[data-behavior="edit_numeric"]').click(function(e) {
    var c = 2 
    alert(this);
    return(false)
  })
})
```

When first loading the show page, the listners are created, at least I can trace them in chrome/safari. The show page has no elements with data-behavior attributes, they are on the partial called with ajax.

```
<%= link_to "Edit Helper","##{builder.object.sequence}","data-behavior" => "edit_contains", :id => "seq_#{builder.object.sequence}"%>
```

Is supposed to open a display:none div to do some JavaScript updating. If I put a breakpoint the the `var c` line, it never gets called. It seems like the remote call kills the listeners.

Do I have to reload the questions.js file on the remote call? or what am I doing wrong?

It seems I've done this before, but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing a block of HTML (hard to tell from your question), then all event listeners attached directly to those elements that are being replaced (which is what you were doing with your `.click()` handlers) will be removed.  Those event handlers were attached to specific elements in the page and if you replaced those elements, then all event handlers on those elements are gone until you install new event handlers on the new elements.

You can work around that by using `.delegate('click', ...)` (before jQuery 1.7) or `.on('click', ...)` (jQuery 1.7+) on a parent object and let the events bubble up to the parent which is not being replaced.  This will then allow your event handlers to work as new objects are created or replaced.

Since you haven't included your HTML, I have to guess, but you could define your event handlers like this in jQuery 1.7+:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '[data-behavior="edit_contains"]', function(e) {
    var c = 1;
    alert(this);
    return(false);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '[data-behavior="edit_numeric"]', function(e) {
    var c = 2; 
    alert(this);
    return(false)
  });
});
```

Ideally, you would replace `document` with a common parent object that is closer to the objects you are replacing, but is not something itself that is replaced.

Comment: Thank you. jquery in rails 3.1.1 is not 1.7, so I used .live().

Comment: There were actually no events triggered on the main page since there were no data-behavior elements, They were in the ajax partial.

Comment: @user1101017 - the StackOverflow community would appreciate it if you changed your username to a meaningful moniker that we had a chance of recognizing if our paths cross again.  As it is you're pseudo-anonymous (we can't remember a stream of seven digits) so we can't associate any personality with you or remember your previous questions/context.

Comment: jQuery recommends `.delegate()` for pre 1.7 and has deprecated `.live()` from all versions.  Your choice, but that's their recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your response from the Rails server, but it seems like it's replacing all the elements with new elements, hence that's why all event listeners are gone.

Have a look at jQuery .live() - http://api.jquery.com/live/ . Using that instead of .click() will ensure that event listeners will be present on all matching elements, including future ones

Comment: Thank you, you don't find this stuff in the rails unobtrusive javascript stuff. .live() worked fine

Comment: jQuery now recommends `.delegate()` for pre 1.7 and `.on()` for 1.7+.  They have deprecated the use of `.live()` for all versions now because of issues it had.